# How to create a model in rails 3 with 2 columns that has a string length = 8 and decimal(2,2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

How can I create a database table with a column that has a string length = 8 and decimal(2,2) using a rails 3 migration?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: I cant find any information about setting the size of a string or a decimal on that page... sorry

Comment: Why do you want to set a string length in the db? It's probably better to add a validation within Rails instead, and not worry too much about the db.

Comment: Frankie Roberto: Relying on the database to enforce data formatting conflicts with clear separation of concerns, but there are more reasons to describe your data more precisely (storage space, db engine constraints, and performance included).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it isn't in the guide so you have to check the docs. See the column method:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html

```
add_table :foo do |t|
  t.string :foobar, :length => 8
  t.decimal :foobat, :precision => 4, :scale => 2
end
```

Comment: thanks! that is ;) but you know how to do when you generate a new model? ex.: "rails g model Test myString:string myDecimal:decimal" or the only way to do it is by editing the migration?

Comment: The model generator builds a scaffold migration for you (no options supported). Except for in the simplest of cases, you should open those up and flesh them out to fit your data (indexes, null allowances, etc).